# Abort AJAX file upload by pressing escape key

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload, abort

I'm trying to `abort()` an AJAX file upload. I've tried adding event listeners and am trying to `abort()` for any `keypress` at all though I'm not seeing anything in the console. This *must* be done without any frameworks.

```
function myFunction()
{
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

 xhr.upload.addEventListener('keydown',function(e)
 {
  //if (e.keyCode==27) {}
  xhr.abort();
  console.log('escape, abort 1?');
 },false);

 xhr.addEventListener('keydown',function(e)
 {
  //if (e.keyCode==27) {}
  xhr.abort();
  console.log('escape, abort 2?');
 },false);
}
```

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` doesn't have a method called `addEventListener`

Comment: `for (i in new XMLHttpRequest()) {console.log('new XMLHttpRequest().'+i);}`

Comment: touché, buried at the bottom of MDN. Let me try again - `XMLHTTpRequest` currently only emits the event `readystatechange` - it does not emit `keydown` or any other event and, thus, will not fire callbacks bound to those events. Use the answer posted by antyrat.

Comment: You're **still** working on this ajax file uploader?  Are you really doing this for paying clients as you said before?  I can't imagine a paying client being this patient for functionality that exists in myriad utilities already written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seven years later I came across my old post and decided to try and figure it out myself. It is possible to embed the `window` event listener; the relevant line of code is at the bottom of the function and works fine in Waterfox and Chrome.

```
function ajax_promise(method,url)
{
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

 return new Promise(function (resolve, reject)
 {
  xhr.onabort = function()
  {
   alert('xhr aborted!');
  }

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function ()
  {
   if (xhr.readyState == 4)
   {
    if (xhr.status == 200) {resolve(xhr);}
    else {reject({status: xhr.status, statusText: xhr.statusText});}
   }
  };

  window.onkeydown = function(event) {if (event.key && event.key == 'Escape') {xhr.abort();}}
  xhr.open(method, url, true);
  xhr.send();
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to attach event to `window` object instead:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// ...
window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode==27) {
        xhr.abort();
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: This is already inside of a function and so I would have to create a global variable and then implement a whole system with an array of requests *or* move the functionality out of the function which can't be done with my setup.

Comment: Why global variable? This `xhr` will go to closure and if you will initialise addEventListener after `xhr` variable is ready then everything should work.

Comment: In order for the `window` event listener to work the `xhr` object must also be a global variable not defined inside of a function.

Comment: @John - that's wrong. JavaScript is lexically scoped. It does not need to be a global. Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7BHPY/